# Replacing depreciated request npm module with got

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am trying to replace requests using depreciated request npm module with got. When I hardcode my api key it works fine.

```
    const custom = got.extend({
        prefixUrl: url,
        responseType: 'json',
        headers: { "X-API-Key": "<myKey>" }
    });

    const response = await custom('<my url>' + limit + '&offset=' + offset + '&format=json');
```

When I try to pass an API key that I retrieve from AWS Secrets Manager it is undefined.

```
    const custom = got.extend({
        prefixUrl: url,
        responseType: 'json',
        headers: apiKey
    });

   const response = await custom('<my url>' + limit + '&offset=' + offset + '&format=json');
```

I was able to do this without a problem with the request module.

```
    const requestInfo = {
        method: 'GET',
        uri: url
        timeout: 300000,
        encoding: null,
        resolveWithFullResponse: true,
        headers: apiKey,
        json: true
    };

    const response = await request(requestInfo);
```

I am sure it is something I am not understanding about the got npm module, but I haven't been able to find an answer in the documentation. Does anyone know why I can't pass the value using got?

Comment: Can you log `apiKey` at the point you call `got.extend` and double-check it contains an object of the form `{'X-API-Key': '<yourKey>'}`? Perhaps it is just the API key without the object wrapper.

Comment: I already checked that. :-(

Comment: I think I'd have to suggest simplifying your code down to the simplest possible scenario that exhibits the problem in a stand-alone manner, and if the solution doesn't present itself in the process, post that (complete, stand-alone) code here and see if others can help find the issue.